# Дублирование ссылок в DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Нужно продублировать **все ссылки** с тегом <a>, без использования jQuery!
Важно дублировать html-тело ссылки полностью!

Такой код (атрибуты могут отсутствовать):

```
 <tr><td>
        <a class="Now One" href="URL_1" bla-bla="54321">
        <span class="jof">Показать на странице</span>
        </a></td><tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td></tr>
        <td>
        <a class="Now Two" href="URL_2" bla-bla="12345">
        <span class="jof">Открыть в полном размере</span></a>
    </td></tr>
```

Нужно привести к следующему виду(форматирование для наглядности:

```
<tr><td>
        <a class="Now One" href="URL_1" bla-bla="54321">
        <span class="jof">Показать на странице</span>
        </a>
        <a class="Now One" href="URL_1" bla-bla="54321">
        <span class="jof">Показать на странице</span>
        </a></td><tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td></tr>
        <td>
        <a class="Now Two" href="URL_2" bla-bla="12345">
        <span class="jof">Открыть в полном размере</span></a>
        <a class="Now Two" href="URL_2" bla-bla="12345">
        <span class="jof">Открыть в полном размере</span></a>

    </td></tr>
```

PS: Классы "Now One" и "Now Two" *не постоянные*.

PPS: Ссылок на странице *множество*. и находятся в разных частях!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for(i=0;i<anchors.length;i+=2){
    var clone = anchors[i].cloneNode(true);
    anchors[i].parentNode.insertBefore(clone,anchors[i]);
}
```

UPD: пока тестировал, обнаружил, что в массив anchors почему-то добавляются новые вставленные элементы. Что бы не искать причину, вместо i++ пришлось написать i+=2;

Comment: Спасибо за отклик! Но.. проблема в том, что получается так, `<a>` вкладывается в `<a>` и тд.

    <a class="Now Two" href="URL_2" bla-bla="12345">
        <span class="jof">Открыть в полном размере</span><a class="Now Two" href="URL_2" bla-bla="12345">
       <span class="jof">Открыть в полном размере</span></a></a>

А нужно, что бы `<a>` добавлялась после `<a>`, как на примере в шапке вопроса..

Comment: @Alex Krass

> пока тестировал, обнаружил, что в массив anchors почему-то добавляются новые вставленные 

потому что это не массив, а коллекция, и это ее фича - обновляться синхронно с деревом:

    > var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
      undefined
    > anchors.constructor.name
      "HTMLCollection"

Comment: @sergus, обновил ответ под ваши требования.
@Fike, мне всегда казалось, что он возвращает массив ссылок на отобранные элементы, как пишут в справочниках. Но оказывается да, обновляющаяся коллекция.

Comment: Всем, большое человеческое спасибо за помощь! Все работает!